# Reliability data for German trains

Tags: germany, poland, berlin, deutsche-bahn, wroclaw

I want to take the ['Kulturzug'](https://www.dbregio-shop.de/index.php/tickets/36/subtickets/0.ticket%7Cproduct_category_36) between Berlin and Wroclaw on August 10th 2019 (dep. 08:25 from Berlin-Lichtenberg, arr. 12:42 in Wroclaw Glowny).

As I will be attending a wedding later that day, it would be good to know how reliable this train has been recently - are there often delays, and if so how long are they?

Is this information available for DB trains?

Comment: German Railway company DB has its reputation but delays are typically in the range of minutes, not hours. No idea about this special train, though!

Comment: "Reliability" and "German trains" in the same sentence. Thanks for the laugh!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Deutsche Bahn* has a toolbox called *[Ist mein Zug pünktlich?](https://www.bahn.de/p/view/service/auskunft/puenktlichkeits_tools.shtml)*.

They also [publish statistics](https://www.deutschebahn.com/puenktlichkeit).

Both are an authoritative source.

---

To my experience, delays are worst with regional trains as they wait for delayed IC/EC and ICE trains so passengers won't miss their regional connections.

Comment: I also checked their current construction site list for that area and your line RB24 https://bauinfos.deutschebahn.com/berlin-bb,6 and found no matching bulletins. No idea about the Polish part of your journey though.

Comment: As for the last paragraph, that seems to depend a lot of where in Germany. For example, I've just returned from a trainspotting vacation in Hamburg, and _there_ it seemed to be routine for ICEs from the south to arrive 30+ minutes late (presumably due to ongoing maintenance work on the HSL south of Hanover). Several times I saw delays of 60 or 75 minutes on the arrival boards. There were plenty of delayed RE/RB too, but the delays were shorter -- rarely above 20 minutes.

Comment: Yes, this is due to the maintenance work between Hildesheim and Göttingen. The ICE trains have to take the old curvy *Leinetal* route for about 100km, which is already full of freight and commuter trains. The latter can't be replaced so the ICEs are sandwiched between trains that stop at all or almost all stations.

Comment: @Janka Your anecdotal impression about regional and ICE-trains does not match with the linked statistics which says regional trains are 93% on time while IC/ICE etc. <70%...

Comment: That's why I wrote *to my experience*. That statistics is to be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: The Kulturzug is not a regular DB train. It's probably not included in the statistics.